# How to execute GIT commands by reading as parameters in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, sh, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run GIT commands by reading as parameters through pipeline script, script has text fields and in first filed i can able to read and able to clone the code with out any issue.

But in the second text I need split the command with "=" and first part will give the folder name, and have to enter into the folder (cd) and need to execute the second part of the command.

I'm able to enter into the folder but cant able to execute the command

**getting the below error**

```
workspace/Test_Groovy_PL@tmp/durable-35d68464/script.sh: line 16: git pull && git fetch --tags && git checkout -b abc rele-1: command not found
```

can you any one please suggest, where i need make the changes so that i get pull and fetch the code

```
pipeline{
    agent any
        parameters{
             text(name: 'GitCheckOutURLs')
             text(name: 'Branches')
             }
        stages{
            stage("Clone and Checkout"){
                steps{
                    deleteDir()     
                    sh '''
                        urls=$GitCheckOutURLs
                        IFS=$'\n' GitCheckOutURLs1=($urls)
                        for urls1 in "${GitCheckOutURLs1[@]}"
                        do
                            git clone $urls1
                        done
                    '''
                }
            }
            stage("Clone and Checkout1"){
                steps{
                    sh '''
                        CheckoutBranches=$Branches
                        IFS=$'\n' CheckOutURLs1=(${CheckoutBranches//$'\n'/ })
                        IFS=$'\n' CheckOutURLs1=($CheckoutBranches)
                        for checkout1 in "${CheckOutURLs1[@]}"
                        do
                            IFS=$'\n' checkout2=(${checkout1//$'\n'/ })
                            IFS=$'=' checkout2=($checkout1)
                            cd $WORKSPACE/${checkout2[0]}
                            ${checkout2[1]}
                        done    
                    '''
                }

    Parameters: 

    GitCheckOutURLs:
    ssh://git@......./dt.git
    ssh://git@......./vss.git

    Branches:
    dt=git pull && git fetch --tags && git checkout -b abc rele-1
    vss=git pull && git fetch --tags && git checkout -b xyz rele-2
```

If I replace **${checkout2[1]} with git pull ..** then the script is working fine, but cant able to execute the same command with the variable.

Comment: What is the problem? Could you share the error?

Comment: Hi Dcalap, question has updated with the error message.